# Typescript 1.4 SDK for build server?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild, typescript, typescript1.4

I've updated to Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, which includes Typescript 1.4.  I've updated my project file with this, and everything works fine locally.

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

However, the build server has not been updated with the Typescript 1.4 SDK.  Builds are now failing with this error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets (95): Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript compiler and tools than is currently installed on this machine.  No compiler was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\tsc.exe.  You may be able to fix this problem by changing the  element in your project file.

Despite the existence of the VisualStudio folder referenced above, Visual Studio is not installed on this machine, and I'd prefer not to install it.  It seems I need to install the Typescript 1.4 SDK, but I can't find a stand-alone installer for it anywhere.  http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download has npm and VS add-in downloads, but no stand-alone SDK.

This seems a little silly, but where can I get a typescript 1.4 SDK from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Visual Studio add-in is also the stand alone Typescript 1.4 installer.

You can get the installer [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304).

Comment: v1.6 available here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6.aspx